# How to group and count random strings?

Tags: python, count

I have several thousand lines of data which looks like the following:

```
TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**  
TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**  
TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**  
TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**  
TATTAT**TCTCCAT**
```

I want to group and count my data to have an output as follows:

```
TTGGGG**TCTCCAT** - 2  
TTGGGG**TCTCCAT** - 2  
TATTAT**TCTCCAT** - 1
```

Since the 6 characters before the character in bold are random, I am not sure how to code for that in python.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    counts = collections.Counter(line.strip() for line in infile)
for seq, count in counts.items():
    print(seq, '-', count)
```

The above solution uses [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
If on the other hand, you'd rather not use helpers built into the standard library, then you could do the following with identical results:

```
counts = {}
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        seq = line.strip()
        if seq not in counts:
            counts[seq] = 0
        counts[seq] += 1
    for seq, count in counts.items():
        print(seq, '-', count)
```

Comment: This is a bit bare-bones. Some sort of explanation might have been nice.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I would have gladly added an explanation if OP had cared to do the same for the question. Clearly, OP doesn't care too much, so I didn't put a whole lot of effort into my answer, beyond it being correct

Comment: Good point, well made. But with your rep score, you really should know better.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: FWIW I think it's reasonable to expect the OP to be able to look up and read the documentation for the [`colections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: added more text and another algorithm to help out OP

Answer (score 0):

First method:

Example:

```
>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1].count(1)
3
```

Hence in your case:

```
>>['TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**','TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**','TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**','TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**','TATTAT**TCTCCAT**'].count('TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**')
```

Second method:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> z = ['TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**',TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**',TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**','TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**','TATTAT**TCTCCAT**']
>>> Counter(z)
Counter({'TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**':2, 'TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**': 2, 'TATTAT**TCTCCAT**': 1})
```

Comment: How would one use the first method to produce the output desired?

Comment: print ['TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**','TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**','TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**','TTCTTC**TCTCCAT**','TATTAT**TCTCCAT**'].count('TTGGGG**TCTCCAT**')
==> prints out 2

Comment: No, I meant if you're reading the values from a file, how do you print a count of each value avoiding repeats if it's a value you've seen before. Without addressing how do to that, your first example seems fairly worthless IMHO.